# Run a Applescript on a locked Mac by keypress or alternative options

Tags: macos, applescript

I have an Applescript written for a specific purpose that launches an application and performs a couple of tasks. I would like to be able to run this script by pressing a key on my keyboard, however, while the Mac is locked. (Note: Mac is only locked, not "asleep")

I'm open to alternative options, if such (or more efficient) options exist.
The above scenario is my "ideal" configuration, the only thing I don't have flexibility on, is that the mac must stay locked for this process.

I have full administrative access to the Mac.

Comment: What purpose is it, and why do you need to press a key?

Comment: I'm not deadset on it being activated by a keypress, if an alternative method is available, I'm open to it. The purpose, as mentioned above is to launch an Applescript.

Edit: Any method of activation is acceptable as long as I am able to control when it happens by doing "x", and meets the criteria that the screen, for this task, is and remains locked.

Comment: I meant rather, what does the Applescript do? There might be a better method.

Comment: The script launches QuickTime and subsequently tells it to record.
Edit: Depending on the end solution, I also have ideas regarding this same concept, utilizing a system of interconnected USB devices in being able to activate or deactivate devices, such as RaspberryPi devices, and such, or having these devices (when triggered by linked motion detectors or other factors) to also perform similar tasks.

Comment: The problem is the fact the computer is "locked" and probably won't accept any keyboard/mouse input other than the login authorization (if you require a password) to unlock. One thing you might be able to do though is "push" a notification to the computer and then it can run the task.

Comment: Hm, I had concerns that might be the case; I wasn't sure if Mac had any similar capabilites to allow actions from the lock/password screen, akin to how you can allow for launching and utilizing certain applications from the iPhone lock screen. But I imagine for my purposes this functionality, were it to exist, would quickly become inadequate. I'm intrigued by the possibility of push notifications. Would this need to come from my iPhone? I'm not entirely familiar with all the means available for sending push notifications.

Comment: How about running a script using `fswatch` that runs your script when a file is created via the network? Or maybe it monitors your Dropbox folder and notices when you create a file in there using your iPhone and then runs your AppleScript?

Comment: Or you can `ssh` into your Mac using an iPad running **Terminus**, or using a PC or other Mac and run your script via your `ssh` session.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I think ssh is going to be the most viable option. It appears that Terminus allows you to save commands, so it looks like that would allow for connecting and issuing the command to run the script in ~2 steps, which is more than reasonable for my purposes. Out of the possible options, it also leaves the most room for expanding the system and adding additional tasks. If you'd like to post that as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it as such.

Comment: I wanted to mention, using Discord the other night on my Mac, while it was locked, I pressed the key I use for "push-to-talk"and it allowed me to speak to the people that were waiting for me. It's interesting to me that the "listener" acknowledged the keypress while the computer was locked. I imagine someone a bit more programming-savvy could write a simple listener program that would function in the same manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use `ssh` to *"get into"* your Mac while the screen is locked and then run your script from the shell. You would probably use `osascript` for that if it is Applescript, by the way.

In order to do this, you will need to ensure the `sshd` is running on your Mac by going to the Apple Menu, then `System Preferences` then `Sharing` and check the box beside `Remote Login`.

In order to `ssh` into your Mac, you could use another Mac, or a PC or the free iPhone/iPad app called `Terminus` which is brilliant for remotely controlling machines via `ssh`.

Rather than have to run a command when you log in, a technique which I often use is to have a user who can only execute a specific function and the very act of logging in does that function and then logs the user out again. So, for example, if I wanted a login that can reboot a machine, I would create a new user called `reboot` and instead of that user having `bash` in `/etc/passwd` as his shell, he would have `/sbin/reboot` as his shell. Just a thought - YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this same thing and when the Mac becomes locked, normal processing will not occur but slow to a crawl, so I had to turn my screens off instead of locking my Mac.  There is no way around it.

Comment: Hi, this doesn't appear to try to answer the question, but to add a 'me too' for a different situation. The OPs desire is to be able to start a specific program while the screen is locked.